# Neologism based songs

Tags: voice

Lacking in music vocabulary I'm finding it hard to articulate, but I am looking for songs (or the genre) that use sounds and made up words purely for its aesthetic quality. The closest thing I can conceive of is something like Adiemus which uses vocals as an instrument where the words have no inherent meaning of themselves. Beatboxing I think comes close too but the 'vocabulary' in beatboxing seems somewhat more limited.

Comment: Check out "scat-singing". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing

Comment: @Olli scat-singing is one class of this.  Since scat involves (usually) sneaking a lot of words into the stream, it's not the same as purely singing a sequence of "voice shapes" such as la-la-fa-tu-tu, e.g.

Answer (score 3):

[Elizabeth Fraser of the Cocteau Twins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvaQXDhg5G4) used to make up/pick up random words just for their sound.

Search terms that may interest you:

- an invented language is called [idioglossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioglossia);
- the broader study of euphony (what sounds good) is [phonaesthetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonaesthetics).

Comment: wow thanks! you read my mind with those search term suggestions! Gotta get reading.

Answer (score 1):

Nat King Cole's "Frim Fram Sauce" comes to mind as does the "Hapsut Song."